# A Riemann Intergrable Problem in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I am going over the following problem in preparation for an exam and am looking for some help with the execution of it.

Consider the function $f$ defined by $[0,2]$ by,

$$ { f }(x)=\begin{cases} 0\quad ,\quad x \in [0,1)  \\ 1\quad ,\quad x\in[1,2]\end{cases} $$

I am trying to prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Using the definition we have been given in class, $f$ is Riemann intergrable if $L(f)=U(f)$

with $L(f)$ being the lower sum, and $U(f)$ being the upper sum.

Here is what I have so far worked out,

Let $\epsilon>0.$ Let $P_{\epsilon}$ be a partition of the interval $[0,2]$ where $P_{\epsilon}=\{[0,1-\epsilon], [1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon],[1+\epsilon,2]\}$

So I Know I need to show that $U(f,P_{\epsilon)}-L(f,P_{\epsilon})=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So I need to compute the sup,inf of this function on any interval and I am not quite sure how to do this.

Also I believe I chose my partition correctly but I am not sure about the $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ value. I calculated this by using the formula $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$ with $[a,b]=[0,2]$

So what I am asking is did I pick $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ correctly, and if so how do i calculate the inf,sup to show that $U(f,P_{\epsilon)}-L(f,P_{\epsilon})=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and therefore $f$ is Riemann intergrable

Comment: I think you mean $U(f,P_\epsilon) - L(f,P_\epsilon)  =  2\epsilon$, because $\mathsf{length}([1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]) = (1+\epsilon) - (1-\epsilon) = 2 \epsilon$..

Comment: yes thanks i will edit that in, could you help me with the rest?

Comment: so is my partition interval wrong then?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your partition, provided you keep $\epsilon < 1$

Comment: okay thanks, would you be able to help me calculate the sup and inf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given the function that is $0$ on $[0,1)$ and $1$ on $[1,2]$.

So we choose a partition, as you have done, $P = [0,1-\epsilon],[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon],[1+\epsilon,2]$, for some fixed $1>\epsilon>0$.

What is $U(f,P)$? To do this, we look at the definition itself:
$$
U(f,P) = \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i) \sup_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x)
$$

So, all we need to understand, are the maximum values that $f$ take on the intervals in the partition.

First, $f$ is zero on $[0,1)$, hence also on $[0,1-\epsilon)$.

The interval $[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$ intersects $[1,2]$, hence the maximum value of $f$ on this interval is $1$.

Similarly, the interval $[1+\epsilon,2]$ is contained in $[1,2]$, hence we have that the maximum of $f$ on this interval is also $1$. Hence:
$$
U(f,P) = ((1+\epsilon) - 0) \times 0 + ((1+\epsilon) - (1 - \epsilon)) \times 1 + (2 - (1 + \epsilon)) \times 1 \\ = 1 + \epsilon
$$

Similarly, we can check that:
$$
L(f,P) = \sum_{[x_i,x_{i+1}] \in P} (x_{i+1} - x_i) \inf_{[x_{i+1},x_i]} f(x)
$$
First, $f$ is zero on $[0,1)$, hence also on $[0,1-\epsilon)$.

The interval $[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$ intersects $[1,2]$, hence the minimum value of $f$ on this interval is $0$.

Similarly, the interval $[1+\epsilon,2]$ is contained in $[1,2]$, hence we have that the minimum of $f$ on this interval is also $1$. Hence:
$$
L(f,P) = ((1+\epsilon) - 0) \times 0 + ((1+\epsilon) - (1 - \epsilon)) \times 0 + (2 - (1 + \epsilon)) \times 1 \\ = 1 - \epsilon
$$

Hence, $U(f,P) - L(f,P) = 2\epsilon$. If you want this quantity to be less than $\epsilon$,  then you can start with the partition above, replacing $\epsilon$ by $\frac \epsilon 4$  for example. But you are done, because as $\epsilon \to 0$, this difference also goes to zero, so the limit (which is $1$) is the integral of the function over $[0,2]$.

In truth, if $f$ is discontinuous at finitely many points (like a step function), then you can repeat the same procedure to obtain similar estimates, and adjust $\epsilon$s to get Riemann integrability. The real difficult result for you at this stage is saying *precisely* which functions are integrable and which are not. That you will learn only after some time.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, it really help clear things up!

Comment: @jh123 You are welcome!